# Drag-Drop Web Parts

Tags: web-part

I try to make web parts move independently between columns. I have the drag-drop code with list items and I want to do drag-drop thing with the web parts. Here is an example web site: http://www.ataturkairport.com/tr-TR/Pages/Main.aspx  I hope that I'm on the right way. If I'm not, I can have your suggestions.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to modify the drag-drop code with web part but I couldn't find how I can do it. Can I use web parts in a code?

Comment: in edit mode you can always drag drop web part, do you wish to provide the facility to general user? and do you wish to persist the change or should the change be local to a user? give a little more details

Comment: The link you mention use a standard jQuery implementation, not specific to SharePoint. I'm quite sure the code is not specific to SharePoint. I believe the company behind the implementation build a custom publishing page, with a lot a specific javascript

Comment: I know it can be in edit mode but I want it for every user. But I don'T know how codes include web parts. Here is code'S demo: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid  . Can you tell me how can I make web parts to be a list item or some idea similar to that?

Comment: I think you are going into territory that no other SharePoint developer has gone before and you would have to completely develop your own infrastructure for this that works as a subset of the web part zone.

Answer (score 1):

With some tweaking you can get Drag and Drop in edit mode to work in SP 2010.
http://blog.pixelmill.com/1161/drag-drop-web-parts-not-working-in-sharepoint-2010-custom-master-page/
But that does not seem to be exactly what you are looking for.

I have never seen that sort of behavior duplicated in a SharePoint site. If I were going about recreating it, though, I would do it within a single web part that had some sort of "canvas" allowing the drag and drop arrangement of different widgets. This would allow reordering of the widgets when not in edit mode.

I think the web part zone infrastructure is a little bit too complex to manage in the way that you would like to be able to drag and drop between web part zones outside of edit mode.

Comment: You'r right. It sounds better then mine. But there will be announcement, weather news, photos and other things. I've done them with independent web parts. How can I carry them? It will be hard without web part.

Comment: I think these widgets are going to have to be pure JavaScript or XSLT wrapped within jQuery UI, KendoUI, or similar.

Comment: If you get something working, please consider writing a blog post about it. I would be very willing to help with your English.

Comment: I'll let you know as soon as I can. Thank you again.